# Evolution will not allow me to download e-mails from exchange server

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange

any ideas that might help me?

When I go to create a new account I select Exchange under the server type. I am not sure which plugin this is using, I do know what it has worked in the past though... So as far as I know the server should be set up to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 Exchange-plugins for Evolution:

- `evolution-exchange` which uses the "Outlook Web Access" interface over the HTTP protocol
- `evolution-mapi` which uses the proprietary MAPI protocol (this is what Outlook uses)

Both ways to access Exchange have to be enabled separately on the server, and probably also in firewalls etc. to work.

Which one are you using, and did you try the other one?

Comment: When I go to create a new account I select Exchange under the server type. I am not sure which plugin this is using, I do know what it has worked in the past though... So as far as I know the server should be set up to work.

Comment: You can see what plugin(s) are installed by searching for them in Software Center (or Synaptic).  But if you were using this for some time, you're probably using `evolution-exchange`, as `evolution-mapi` is quite new.

Comment: Make sure mapi is installed on the Exchange server. Some Exchnage Admin disable it for security reasons.

Comment: Looks like evolution-mapi is going to work. Thanks